# Yahoo API - Unable to request new access token once previous access token has expired

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, yahoo-api

I am attempting to use Yahoo's API for fantasy football. I am able to receive an access token and refresh token initially, but once that access token has expired, I am unable to get another one.

My code is as follows:

```
from requests import Request, get, post
import webbrowser
import base64

baseURL = 'https://api.login.yahoo.com/'
oauthENDPOINT = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth"


## Generate a url using the endpoint and parameters above
params = {'client_id' : client_id,
          'redirect_uri' : "oob",
          'response_type' : 'code'}
p = Request('GET', oauthENDPOINT, params=params).prepare()

webbrowser.open(p.url)
```

The last line sends me to the Yahoo website where I allow myself access and receive `authCode`.

```
encoded = base64.b64encode((client_id + ':' + client_secret).encode("utf-8"))
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded.decode("utf-8")}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
data = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'redirect_uri': 'oob',
    'code': authCode}

tokenResponse = post(baseURL + 'oauth2/get_token', headers=headers, data=data)
tokenResponseJSON = tokenResponse.json()
access_token = tokenResponseJSON['access_token']
refresh_token = tokenResponseJSON['refresh_token']
```

I now have all the information necessary to examine the settings of my league (for example).

```
fbURL = 'https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2'

leagueURL1 = f'{fbURL}/leagues;league_keys=nfl.l.{leagueID}/settings'

headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}

response2 = get(leagueURL1, headers=headers,params={'format': 'json'})
```

The above works as expected. However, the `access_token` lasts for 3600 seconds and once that time has expired I am unable to request a new one, using my `refresh_token`. My attempt:

```
accessTokenData = {
    'grant_type': 'refresh_token',
    'redirect_uri': 'oob',
    'code': authCode,
    'refresh_token': refresh_token
}

accessTokenResponse = post(baseURL + 'oauth2/get_token', headers=headers, data=accessTokenData)
accessTokenJSON = accessTokenResponse.json()
```

In the above, I am hoping to receive a new `access_token`, but instead `accessTokenJSON` is this:

```
{'error': {'localizedMessage': 'client request is not acceptable or not supported',
  'errorId': 'INVALID_INPUT',
  'message': 'client request is not acceptable or not supported'}}
```

Up to this point I have been following [these steps](https://joinative.com/yahoo-gemini-api-oauth-authentication-python), which worked well up to this point. What am I doing wrong? I understand many Python users use `yahoo_oauth` or `rauth` for authentication, but that involves saving the `client_id` and `client_secret` in a `.json` file separately and I'm looking to load those in dynamically. I don't think I'm very far away from succeeding, but I'm just missing something when it comes to generating a new `refresh_token`. All help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to referring back to our guide.

Managed to reproduce your error and it's really simple to solve.

You are redefining the `headers` variable in your request to the fantasyspot url.

The `headers` variable should be the same in the call for requesting a new `access_token` using the `refresh_token` as it was when initially getting both tokens using the `auth_code`.

So just define `header` before making requesting a new `access_token`. Should look like the the following:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded.decode("utf-8")}',
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
response = post(base_url + 'oauth2/get_token', headers=headers, data=data)
```

Should work now.

Recommend using different variable names for the `headers` used for getting an `access_token` and the one used to the fantasy sport url.

Comment: Jonas, is there any way I could chat with you about a really similar issue I am having with this setup? I've tried implementing what you've said here, but I'm still a bit unclear, and still getting the same error as OP.